# splitting image results in unhandled exception error

Tags: c++, opencv, image-processing, split

I am currently planning on splitting my image into 3 channels so i can get the RGB values of an image to plot a scatter graph so i can model is using a normal distribtion calculating the covariance matrix, mean, etc.
then calculate distance between the background points and the actual image to segment the image.

Now in my first task, i have wrote the following code.

```
    VideoCapture cam(0);
//int id=0;
Mat image, Rch,Gch,Bch;
vector<Mat> rgb(3);         //RGB is a vector of 3 matrices

namedWindow("window");
while(1)
{
    cam>>image;
split(image,rgb);
    Bch = rgb[0];
    Gch = rgb[1];
    Rch = rgb[2];
```

but as soon as it reaches the split function, i step through it, it causes a unhandled exception error. access violation writing location 0xfeeefeee

i am still new to opencv, so am not used to dealing with unhandled exception error.

thanks

Comment: Check if the `image` has been captured correctly. After `cam>>image`, add this... `if(image.empty()) { cout<<"Image Not Captured"; break;}`

Comment: i tried that and image is being captured properly but error still remains

Answer (score 1):

It sounds as if split expects there to be three instances of `Mat` in the `rgb` vector.
But you have only prepared it to hold three items - it is actually empty.

Try adding three items to the vector and run again.

Comment: could you give an example of code i could try. I tried assigning the 3 matrix channels to the vector rgb[0]=Rch; but still error. i also tried rgb[0]=image; same with rgb[1] rgb[2] just give it any matrix and still error.

Comment: Just add the three `Mat`s `Bch`, `Gch` and `Rch` in the appropriate order to the `Vector`

Comment: i did try that aswell but still the error you mean, that since it is in BGR format as always set it to rgb[0] = Bch; rgb[1]=Gch; rgb[2]=Rch; and i still get error. i even tried other way round rgb[0]=Rch and so on

Comment: i also tried push back after removing the (3) and still error.

Comment: Then it is something with the split function itself. Cannot help you more without that one.

Comment: CV_EXPORTS void split(const Mat& m, vector<Mat>& mv ); i can't find the code where it processes it

Comment: when i decide to step into split, it won't it just says writing violation error and points to res = _heap_alloc(size);

Comment: ahh - it's an external library. Then I can understand that it's hard to show the code :D Given the additional error you show now I'd say that the image (or rather 3x image) is too large for your heap. How big is the image? Could you try with a really small image to see if it works?

Comment: is there a way instead of just splitting it just access the pixel values of the image i tried the following vector<float> rgb(3); for(i=1;i<image.rows;i++) for(j=1;j<image.cols;j++) rgb[0] = image.at<float>(i,j)[0]; when i step through it all the values in the vector are zero, i want to store the rgb pixel values in a vector but i can't even do that

Comment: Seeing how you use the at operator of a matrix class I can only say: Read the manual. at() gives you a float, not a list. To manually separate RGB values from the image you have to know how they realise that in the matrix. I would go with the `split()` function. So read up on it in the [reference](http://opencv.willowgarage.com/documentation/cpp/core_operations_on_arrays.html#index-8012)

Comment: that's what i did vector containing 3 floats, i assigned the output of at to one of the floats in the vector.

Comment: No you didn't. You assigned the least significant byte of the float recieved from `at()` to the first float in the vector. Big difference.

Comment: im confused, what should it have been instead of rgb[0] = image.at<Vec3b>(i,j)[0]

Comment: Just remove the `[0]` after `at()`

Comment: when i try that i.e. rgb[0] = image.at<Vec3b>(i,j) it says no suitable conversion function from Vec3b to float exists so i decided to change Vec3b to float and i get unhandled exception error.

Comment: so anything else i can try

Comment: what if i tried a certain way that when i cout the pixel value i get something on the output resembling a smiley face is there a way to convert this to numbers

Answer (score 0):

Although this is an old issue I would like to share the solution that worked for me. Instead of `vector<Mat> rgb(3);` I used `Mat channels[3];`. I realized there is something wrong with using vector when I was not able to use split even on an image loaded with imread. Unfortunately, I cannot explain why this change works, but if someone can that would be great.